# How to get LOCAL page DIV content and post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**How to get LOCAL page DIV content and post**

Basically let me explain a bit of my issue

In this page [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkBgM/3/)

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var new_img = $('#' + data).clone();
    $('#' + ev.target.id).html(new_img);
}    
</script>
```

I allow use to pull image into the div. Now I wanna add a form method post and a submit button

On submit it will post to maybe page2.php and page2.php need get the content of the 2 div square with the image "name" or "id" that user pull inside or can say the current div content as of user selection.

How can I achieve that. Thanks! Look at my jsFiddle page to get more understanding on what I trying ask :)

Thanks !

---

One possible thing I could think of is using hidden field. I create 4 hidden field namely div1_selection , div2_selection, div3_selection, div4_selection and their values is blank at initial.

When Drag & drop, their value will be the id of the img that is drop on it.
My question is how do I get the value of the img that is drop and set at the hidden field (if hidden field method work)

Updated Attempt:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#sub").submit(function(){
  var img1  =   $($("#div1").html()).attr("id");
  var img2  =   $($("#div2").html()).attr("id");
  var img3  =   $($("#div3").html()).attr("id");
  var img4  =   $($("#div4").html()).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'setImage.php?img1='+$img1+'&img2='+$img2+'&img3='+$img3+'&img4='+$img4,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {$("#newhtml").html(data);}
    });
  });
});
</script>
<form action="" method="post" id="sub">
// some codes as on jsFiddle
<div id="newhtml"></div>
```

My `setImage.php` code

```
<?php
$img1 = $_GET['img1'];
$img2 = $_GET['img2'];
$img3 = $_GET['img3'];
$img4 = $_GET['img4'];
echo "IMG 1" . $img1 . " | IMG 2 " . $img2 . " | IMG 3 " . $img3 . " | IMG 4 " . $img4;
?>
```

I trying display the return result on newhtml but doesn't work. is there any wrong with the  ajax implementation that I do?

Thanks

---

**Latest Update:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#input").click(function(){  var img1  = $($("#div2").html()).attr("id");
  var img1  = $($("#div3").html()).attr("id");
  var img2  = $($("#div3").html()).attr("id");
  var img3  = $($("#div3").html()).attr("id");
  var img4  = $($("#div4").html()).attr("id");
$.ajax({
url: 'setImage.php',
data:{image1:img1,image2:img2,image3:img3,image4:img4},
type: 'GET',
success: function (data) {
alert(data)
$("#newhtml").html(data);
}
});

  });
});
</script>
```

The variable was not send over, it just return the default echo message but its seem it is unable to capture the value of img1,img2,img3,img4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the id of image:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#sub").submit(function(){
  var img1  = $($("#div2").html()).attr("id");
  var img2  = $($("#div3").html()).attr("id");
  var img3  = $($("#div3").html()).attr("id");
  var img4  = $($("#div4").html()).attr("id");

$.ajax({
url: 'setImage.php',
data:{image1:img1,image2:img2,image3:img3,image4:img4},
type: 'GET',
success: function (data) {
alert(data)
$("#newhtml").html(data);
}
});

  });
});
</script>
```

Html code: Add form tag

```
<form action="" id="sub">
<table>
<tr>
<td><p><b>Main Image</b></p><div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div></td>
<td><p><b>Image 2</b></p><div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> </td>
<td><p><b>Image 3</b></p><div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>

 <img id="drag1" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2013/02/thumbnail32.jpg" alt="img01"/></a>
 <img id="drag2" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/html5-css3-wireframing/html5-logo.jpg" alt="img02"/></a>
 <img id="drag3" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)"src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2012/12/thumb-1.jpg" alt="img03"/></a>
 <input type="submit" value="send">
 </form>
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the value of img1, img2 using php? Thanks for helping

Comment: Your welcome...Use ajax to send your javascript value to 'page2.php' and retrieve it via $_POST or $_GET in 'page2.php'..:)

Comment: Hi again, I did some code changes, I updated my question, please take a look :) Thanks again.

Comment: I tried the code but the variable like not reaching the php page, its return empty, IMG 1 = | IMG 2 = | IMG 3 = | IMG 4 = |